# Why do I not get a warning for casting a pointer to an int?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, int

The following piece of code gives a warning for casting from a pointer to an int which makes a perfect sense

```c
int foo[] = {1, 2, 3};
#define bar(x) foo[(int)(x) % 3]
char *baz = "quux";
bar(baz);
```

On the other hand, the following code compiles without any warnings (regardless of the fact that it may cause a runtime error)

```c
#include <ctype.h>
// some code
char *baz = "quux";
isalpha(baz);
```

When I opened ctype.h to look at `isalpha`, I found that it is a macro that uses a couple of other macros

```c
#  define _ISbit(bit)   (1 << (bit))

enum
{
    // some identifiers
    _ISalpha = _ISbit (2),
    // some identifiers
};

extern const unsigned short int **__ctype_b_loc (void)
 __THROW __attribute__ ((__const__));

# define __isctype(c, type) \
((*__ctype_b_loc ())[(int) (c)] & (unsigned short int) type)

# define isalpha(c) __isctype((c), _ISalpha)
```

As you can probably see, the result of expanding the `isalpha` macro still explicitly casts the pointer `baz` to an `int`. However, this does not give any warnings when compiled. So apparently both pieces of code perform the same operation (i.e., casting a `char *` to an `int`), yet one gives a warning and the other does not. Why?

*NOTE: compilation commands with the same options were used to compile the programs that contained these pieces of code.*

Compiler version:

```
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2
```

Comment: First snippet does not give me any warning with `gcc` and `-Wall  -std=c99 -pedantic` options.

Comment: Indeed. Can you add information on compiler, version, etc?

Comment: @ouah here's a [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/UghzkIz.png)!

Comment: @EricPlaton the version of the compiler is also in the [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/UghzkIz.png)!

Comment: Weird. I'm running `4.7.2 20120921 (Red Hat 4.7.2-2)` and compiled that exact code in the screen shot, and I only received two warnings about statements with no effect.

Comment: @Kareem ok gcc 4.7 does not warn but gcc 4.8 starts to warn. See my answer on why you don't get the warning on the second program with gcc 4.8

Comment: With the second code snippet, I get the error: `error: array subscript is not an integer` when used with and without `-Wall`. I'm using gcc 4.7.3.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first program does not warn with `gcc` `4.7` but gives a warning with versions `4.8`.

The second program does not warn because the macro definition is in a system header. Add `-Wsystem-headers` to get the warning with the second program.

From gcc documentation (emphasize mine)

> -Wsystem-headers
>
> Print warning messages for constructs found in system header files.
>      **Warnings from system headers are normally suppressed**, on the
>      assumption that they usually do not indicate real problems and
>      would only make the compiler output harder to read.

Comment: With `-Wsystem-headers` warns about the cast *in the macro definition*. The specific warning I get is "cast from pointer to integer of different size". If I compile with `-Wsystem-headers -m32`, so that `int` and `char*` are both 32 bits, the warning goes away. The cast is still questionable (and, in this case, meaningless), but the compiler doesn't warn about it because there's no size change.

Comment: @KeithThompson if you add `-m32` both the first program and the second program will no longer have the warning. What I think disputable is the name of the warning `-Wpointer-to-int-cast` is misleading at it warns only if you cast a pointer to an integer AND if the size of the pointer and of the integer type are different.

Comment: The cast is not nonsense. `is*` functions take in an int so the value must be converted as if by assignment into a parameter, so that `isspace(32.0)` and other abominations work ..

Answer (score 5):

The C standard permits any standard library function to be additionally implemented as a macro. The requirements for such a macro definition ([N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) section 7.1.4) are:

> Any function declared in a header may be additionally implemented as a
>   function-like macro defined in the header, so if a library function is
>   declared explicitly when its header is included, one of the techniques
>   shown below can be used to ensure the declaration is not affected by
>   such a macro. Any macro definition of a function can be suppressed
>   locally by enclosing the name of the function in parentheses, because
>   the name is then not followed by the left parenthesis that indicates
>   expansion of a macro function name. For the same syntactic reason, it
>   is permitted to take the address of a library function even if it is
>   also defined as a macro. The use of #undef to remove any macro
>   definition will also ensure that an actual function is referred to.
>   Any inv ocation of a library function that is implemented as a macro
>   shall expand to code that evaluates each of its arguments exactly
>   once, fully protected by parentheses where necessary, so it is
>   generally safe to use arbitrary expressions as arguments. Likewise,
>   those function-like macros described in the following subclauses may
>   be invoked in an expression anywhere a function with a compatible
>   return type could be called.

The macro definition for a library function such as `isalpha()` must work correctly for correct arguments, but it's *not* required to diagnose incorrect arguments. Since the macro definition is explicitly permitted by the C standard, if the implementation provides such a macro then *there is no function call*, and so the constraint that prohibits passing a `char*` argument to a function expecting an `int` does not apply.

If there's an actual function call, then passing a `char*` argument to an actual function expecting an `int` argument is a constraint violation, requiring a diagnostic. There is no implicit conversion from `char*` to `int`.

Here's a small program that illustrates the issue:

```
#include <ctype.h>
int main(void) {
    char *p = "hello";
    isalpha(p);   // line 4, possible macro invocation
    (isalpha)(p); // line 5, actual function call
#undef isalpha
    isalpha(p);   // line 7, actual function call
}
```

And here's the result of compiling it with `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic` (gcc 4.8.2):

```
c.c: In function ‘main’:
c.c:5:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘isalpha’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
     (isalpha)(p); // line 5, actual function call
     ^
In file included from c.c:1:0:
/usr/include/ctype.h:111:1: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
 __exctype (isalpha);
 ^
c.c:7:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘isalpha’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
     isalpha(p);   // line 7, actual function call
     ^
In file included from c.c:1:0:
/usr/include/ctype.h:111:1: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
 __exctype (isalpha);
 ^
```

On line 5, the parentheses around `isalpha` prevent the macro expansion, exposing the function itself. On line 7, the actual function is exposed because the macro definition has been removed.

An actual function call performs an *implicit* conversion,  not a cast; since there is no implicit conversion from `char*` to `int`, the compiler issues a diagnostic. (It could issue a fatal warning, but gcc is somewhat lax about implicit conversions, though a warning does satisfy the standard's requirements.) With the macro, the conversion is performed by an explicit cast operator, which the compiler doesn't warn about by default.

Note that, depending on the implementation, all three calls could be actual function calls. Macro definitions for standard library functions are *optional*. The GNU C library provides a macro definition for `isalpha` because the macro definition can be substantially more efficient than a function call (though an inline function might be equally efficient).

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question

Comment: @pat: I believe it does.  Would you care to expand on that?  And I've expanded my explanation a bit; see the next to last paragraph.

Comment: The warning that the OP got was not about an implicit conversion from pointer to integer, but about an explicit cast from pointer to integer *of different size* (presumably, he has a system where pointers are not the same size as `int`s).  He should have received the same warning from the explicit cast in the `isalpha` macro as he did from the identical cast in his own code, but he did not.